# ElasticSearch aggregation - Group the entire document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch and I'm trying to discover its features. **[ElasticSearch 8.11]**

I'm trying to group my documents by name or id

What I've managed to do so far is to obtain the number of elements with the id

Mapping:

```
       'aggs' => [
            'group_by_id' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'ID',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Result:

```
"aggregations": {
        "group_by_id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 31,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 1,
                    "doc_count": 143
                },
                {
                    "key": 2,
                    "doc_count": 80
                },
                {
                    "key": 3,
                    "doc_count": 68
                },
                {
                    "key": 4,
                    "doc_count": 65
                },
                {
                    "key": 5,
                    "doc_count": 63
                },
                {
                    "key": 6,
                    "doc_count": 43
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Getting the number of documents per id is interesting for me, but I would also like, is to have the whole document that falls into the different groups

I tried looking further into aggregation, trying "composite", "histogram", without much success.

For example, if I had a dataset like this :

```js
[
    {
        "idFamily": 1,
        "labelItem": "MyItem",
        "itemPrice": 100
    },
    {
        "idFamily": 1,
        "labelItem": "MySpecialItem",
        "itemPrice": 100
    },
    {
        "idFamily": 2,
        "labelItem": "MyIncredibleItem",
        "itemPrice": 100
    },
    {
        "idFamily": 3,
        "labelItem": "MyGreatItem",
        "itemPrice": 100
    },
    {
        "idFamily": 3,
        "labelItem": "MySuperItem",
        "itemPrice": 100
    },
    {
        "idFamily": 3,
        "labelItem": "MyAwesomeItem",
        "itemPrice": 100
    }
]
```

I'd like to group them on "idFamily" and therefore have the rest of the document

Don't hesitate to ask for more information about my request. Thank you for your time!